# How to Add Double Quotes in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Sorry for Asking very Basic Question. I am Doing SVN Export with the help of shell Script and Cygwin.Following is the Shell Script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Svn_path="$1 
echo "Destination_Path="$2 
echo "Svn_version="$3 
echo "Svn_username="$4 
echo "Svn_password="$5 
svn export $1 $2 -r $3 --username $4 --password $5 --force --non-interactive
```

This Script works Fine When Destination_path Does not contains Space. eg:-**`D:\Test`**.
If My Destination_Path Contains Space it Won't Work.eg:-**`D:\Test Folder`**

Solution For this I have to Pass `$2` parameter in Double Quotes. How to Do this.

Comment: It seems you already know the solution... just pass it in double quotes.  Bash will still expand them inside double (but not single) quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, well, you simply add double quotes around $2. You do this using a keyboard normally, but [Google also has Morse input pads and other HIDs](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2133337551109399901).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Svn_path=$1" 
echo "Destination_Path=$2"
echo "Svn_version=$3"
echo "Svn_username=$4"
echo "Svn_password=$5"
svn export "$1" "$2" -r "$3" --username "$4" --password "$5" --force --non-interactive
```

Always add double quotes where word expansion is not desired.